# DynamoDB - Most efficient/cheap way of getting a objects from a list of partition keys?

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb, serverless, dynamodb-queries

Let's say in my client I have a list of PKs :

```
PKs = [uuid1, uuid2, uuid3, uuid4, ...]
```

And I need to get the objects that have these corresponding PKs.

I can think of 3 ways :

**Transaction**

Using TransactGetItems, I can fetch 10 items at a time, so I would just get each item individually untill I get them all

**Batch get Items**

Same as Transaction, but not transactional and I can fetch 25 items at a time.

**Query with filter (probably messy)**

I could instead have a GSI that has a immutable attribute as Partition key, and set the original Partition key as a attribute, and I could just chain a bunch of "ORs" in the condition expression.

For example (boto3):

```
table.query(
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('gsi1_pk').eq('metadata'),
    #Bunch of ORs togheter
    FilterExpression=Attr('pk').eq('uuid1') | Attr('pk').eq('uuid2') ...
    Index='GSI1-Index1'
)
```

Now, according to the pricing page :

> DynamoDB charges one read request unit for each strongly consistent
>   read (up to 4 KB), two read request units for each transactional read,
>   and one-half read request unit for each eventually consistent read

I'm not sure what 1 read is, does it considers every object returned or every object scanned? Will each different request be 1 RCU at minimum or do they sum untill it reaches 1 RCU?

Which of the 3 examples above would be the cheapest following DynamoDB pricing system? Is there another way of doing this?

Bonus points for the calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well transactions should be your last option since this has nothing to do with transactional logic.

`BatchGetItems` consumes 1RCU per item, however, `Query` consumes RCU depending on the total size of the items **queried** (not returned!!). If you were to query a table and return 100 items but with 1kb size each (without filter) it would be 400kb and therefore 10 RCU consumed (calculations might be wrong, writing very fast, but you get the idea). So query is much more cheaper in many cases, EXCEPT YOURS. In your case you just scan the entire table since HASH is something static as far as I understand.

Your best option is `BatchGetItems` but there is a big **however** here...

How do you end up having only ID's of what you want? This isn't a NoSQL pattern. What you probably do is normalizing data which is not for DynamoDB. You should denormolize it so that where you can get those ID list you get their relavent attributes as well with it. If you query something and get ID's then another request to IDs simply say that its NORMALIZED and DynamoDB isn't good for it.

I would suggest you re-consider you data design and access patterns.

Comment: I'm only using this for one case where there is a many-to-many in my application. O sort of estimated that this would end up cheaper than having to keep several duplicates up to date, especially since there's no batch update/delete in DynamoDB

Comment: That i say batch get is the way to go. But if its simple key value lookup I would consider Redis which in many cases cheaper.. Just a suggestion.